# If a flagged post is edited before a moderator sees the flag, how do they deal with it?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/97918/3192) as "not an answer". The [initial version](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/97918/1) I flagged was:

> Unfortunately your company has the expectation on you because you are employed. If you are not able to meet the deadlines, you are not qualified for your job. That's the whole point for probation.
>
> Your company has the rights to fire you and hire another programmer who will do better job than you.

This read more like a comment, and did not answer the question, which was: "How should I professionally communicate to my manager that the issues with the code may cause me to miss the deadline?"

I posted a comment on the answer pointing this out (I deleted the comment later), and the answer was subsequently edited to include the below additional paragraph:

> You don't communicate or negotiate with your manager. No excuse. You work on it professionally and do the best you can. Work very very hard. You do exactly you were told. Do it or leave the job.

The flag has since been marked as disputed.

Is this because when a moderator saw the flag, they were presented with the updated version (which did include an answer)?

Note: I don't really mind if the flag was "wrongly" marked as disputed. I am just interested in improving my understanding of the rules and how the system works.

Comment: I think disputed flags are only a result of the review queue. [This Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141400/260884) helped me understand the difference between disputed and declined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The flag has since been marked as disputed. Is this because when a moderator saw the flag, they were presented with the updated version (which did include an answer)?

No. As David mentioned [this was the result](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/62158) of the [Low Quality review queue](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts). In fact, since that review completed, another user flagged this as Not An Answer which created [a new Low Quality review queue entry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/62183) which is still open as I'm writing this.

Not an Answer flags are sent to the review queue first. There is a delay before moderators are alerted of Low Quality flags but that delay is tuned for Stack Overflow meaning that most of those flags do end up in our review list. I tend not to prioritise these as the queue does resolve most of these after some time. Most of the time I only slap on a post notice or flag it as Low Quality so the review queue can sort it out.

If your *flag* is disputed that's almost always an automatic action. Moderators typically only decline flags or dismiss/mark them as helpful, one exception being the "clearing" of a spam flag. For more on disputed flags check:

- [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)
- [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

Note that moderators also get flags for "disputed reviews" where the review resulted in a "Looks OK" but did get Recommend Deletion flags or where the author of a review-deleted post [undeleted it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable). But I believe those aren't explicitly visible to users as they all mark the original flags as helpful.

> If a flagged post is edited before a moderator sees the flag, how do they deal with it?

It depends. The flag overview page we have has only shows the first few sentences of a post which means we almost always end up clicking through to the actual post. Only one-line comments posted as answers are typically handled from that page. Once we open the post we'll check if the flag is *currently* still valid. If it is we'll take the appropriate action. If the post has been improved since we'll usually check the edit history to confirm that it was in a poor state originally and then dismiss the flag as helpful. Only flags that weren't correct at the time they were raised are typically declined.

Comment: In addition, I believe "disputed" always means that it was handled by some system process.  Mods can mark flags helpful or decline them; we don't have a "dispute" button.  Most disputed flags that I've seen are due to mixed reviews.  I *think* a VLQ flag is also disputed if there's an edit, because VLQ means "can't fix" and an edit means someone thought it could be fixed.  (This is a reason not to make trivial edits on posts that will still be bad afterwards; correcting the punctuation in an incoherent rant doesn't actually help anybody.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Indeed, disputed flags are always automatic. I'll add some links to the meta.

Comment: some recent LQ reviews make me feel like I'm at Stack Overflow, any garbage "Looks OK" as long as it appears to say something about the question ([1](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/60183 "example"), [2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/61807 "example"), [3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/61796 "example"), [4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/61423 "example"))